# How to map shared Content Blocks to Templated in Sitefinity 5.2?

Tags: sitefinity-5

I just Migrated my 3.7 website to 5.2 Website, but I noticed that the Generic Content in 3.7 Project have been converted to Shared Content blocks in 5.2. And most importantly not all (only few are likned to pages, i.e., Used in pages column has "Not used" value).

I searched a lot but couldn't find any way to map these blocks to the pages as they were in 3.7 Project.

However, I was trying to follow tutorial:
http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/user-guide/widgets/content-widgets-group/configuring-the-content-block-widget

But I didn't see any option such as "Select from existing shared content button" in Edit Template mode, I get this option in Edit page mode & when I set the Content by selecting the existing Content it's not displayed in View mode, but it's displayed in edit mode.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the introduction of Sitefinity v4, shared content is no longer available for templates, just for pages. They removed that ability unfortunately due to architectual reasons and performance issues.

The official comment on how to solve it at the moment, is by using inherited templates, where you drop a normal content block on a 'parent' template and thus its child templates inherit it while keeping a single point of edit.

As a **non-recommendation** 'hack', you can activate it, as described [here](http://jbokkers.posterous.com/shared-content-in-sitefinity-4-templates). But keep in mind the response from Telerik:

> it will lead to performance problems. This is why this feature is
> disabled by default, and we do not recommend using it.

But there is also good news when you read the [Sitefinity 5.3 roadmap](http://www.sitefinity.com/product/see-also/roadmap) which is scheduled for release end december 2012:

> The 5.3 release includes the below improvements:
> Shared content is now available to use inside page templates

Hope this helps,
Jochem.